# WebDriverWait Syntax Errors

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

Running OS X and Python 3.5.1.

Simply wondering what the proper context is for WebDriverWait to search for an xpath then proceed to click on it once the containing webpage is loaded.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='maincontent']/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/button")))
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='maincontent']/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/button")
a.click()
```

The error code is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hansh/Desktop/markets.py", line 22, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='maincontent']/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/button")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 258, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='maincontent']/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/button"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/b3/h2pq8lmx4p11tb5h3m49xbth0000gn/T/tmpb9uhnk6f/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///var/folders/b3/h2pq8lmx4p11tb5h3m49xbth0000gn/T/tmpb9uhnk6f/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/b3/h2pq8lmx4p11tb5h3m49xbth0000gn/T/tmpb9uhnk6f/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/b3/h2pq8lmx4p11tb5h3m49xbth0000gn/T/tmpb9uhnk6f/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/b3/h2pq8lmx4p11tb5h3m49xbth0000gn/T/tmpb9uhnk6f/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits), the correct syntax is a tuple where the first element is a locator type and the second is a locator value. Rewrite it this way:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
presence_of = EC.presence_of_element_located
wait.until(presence_of((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='maincontent']/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/button")))
```

Also, note that the timeout value you pass into `WebDriverWait` constructor is *in seconds*, not milliseconds. You've probably meant `10` instead of `10000`.